# Help required with local wordpress setup

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, xampp

I recently had a problem with Windows on my computer. I removed the hard drive, put it in a usb casing and I am now using it as an external drive on a new computer. I only have access to all the documents under C drive.

On the new pc: I installed xampp and copied the htdocs files from the old hard drive to the new computer. I need to install the database now. Are the php files stored somewhere on the C drive?

Thank you :)